# Leaflet, creating path using an array for options

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Here's how I draw a polygon:

```
var area1 =
L.polygon([[35.518229203901846, 35.786504745],
          [35.5179672275963, 35.78861832618]],
        {
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        color: '#ff0000',
        stroke: 1,
        fill: 1,
        weight: 5,
        opacity: 0.5,
        fillOpacity: 0.05
        });
```

I'd like to define a couple of the properties (say: color & fillColor) earlier in a single variable (array, maybe?), THEN placing that variable along with the rest of the properties in the polygon creation statement, any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [L.extend](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#util-extend) utility function to merge two objects:

```
var options = {
    fillColor: '#ff0000',
    color: '#ff0000'
}

L.polygon([[10, 10],[-10,10], [-10,-10], [10,-10]], L.extend(options, {
    stroke: 1,
    fill: 1,
    weight: 5,
    opacity: 0.5,
    fillOpacity: 0.05
})).addTo(map);
```

Working example at Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6LGdNVrtilUxmtoLRcL8?p=preview